# Why does `where` give an "undefined method" error in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to get all the feedbacks with a specific attribute. I am using this code:

```
def index
  feedbacks = Feedback.all
  if params[:tag]
    @average_customer_rating = feedbacks.where('buyer_feedback_date is not null').rated(Feedback::FROM_BUYERS).average(:buyer_rating) || 0
    @products = Product.includes(:images).tagged_with(params[:tag]).order('DESC').limit(22)
  else
    @products = Product.includes(:images).all
    @average_customer_rating = feedbacks.where('buyer_feedback_date is not null').rated(Feedback::FROM_BUYERS).average(:buyer_rating) || 0
  end
end
```

and Rails shows this error:

```
undefined method `where' for []:Array
```

Why can't I use `where` here and how do I fix it?

Comment: You can not use where on array

Comment: Where will work on `Activerecord`

Comment: sorry? i did not get

Comment: What you did not get?

Comment: i did not get why i can't use where  in a array

Comment: and in this case should i use find?

Comment: Where does `feedbacks` come from?

Comment: can you show what is the data you have for feedbacks

Comment: Stefan come from feedbacks model but i'm trying to iterate on the home page

yes gates, which data you would like me to show?

Comment: `feedback` is either a local variable or a method. Please show the assignment (i.e. `feedback = ...`) or the method definition (i.e. `def feedback ... end`).

Comment: Stefan, ok. just a moment!

Comment: Thanks for the update. Are you using an older version of Rails? IIRC, `all` used to return an array in Rails 3.x.

Comment: Stefan, yes i'm on rails 3.2. because of some code that i'm using have that reserved name thing.

Comment: Try `feedbacks = Feedback.scoped` instead of `feedbacks = Feedback.all`. That should give you an `ActiveRecord::Relation` which you can narrow down further via `where`.

Comment: ok i gonna try it!

Comment: hey Stefan, thank you very much. worked! :) and man, this thing is very tricky Jesus!

Comment: i gonna check more about this scope method. i've never heard about this  on controller.
anyway thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Rails 3.x, [`all`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-all) returns an array:

```
feedbacks = Feedback.all  # <- an array
feedbacks.where(...)      # <- fails
```

To get an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, you have to use [`scoped`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-scoped):

```
feedbacks = Feedback.scoped  # <- an ActiveRecord::Relation
feedbacks.where(...)         # <- works
```

See [Working with scopes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2/active_record_querying.html#working-with-scopes) for more examples.

---

Note that this distinction is not needed in Rails 4 anymore – `scoped` was deprecated in favor of [`all`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.0/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-all) which now returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation`.

Comment: yes i saw this. so was not my fault but the rails version!
and Stefan thank you very much!

Comment: Of course, it's always the tools ;-) You're welcome!

Comment: thank you. i would like to upvote your answer but, i can't vote!

Comment: @nakapaka1 invest a little more time in writing your questions and you will likely receive more upvotes (see [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)). The privilege to [vote up](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) is awarded at 15 reputation.

Comment: I have upvoted for the sake of upvoting consistency. Mostly for “it's always the tools” comment :)

Comment: Sure @Stefan! and thank you :)

@mudasobwa, indeed the vote is a good tool! if the person make  a good use. because, seems that some people love downvote for the sake of downvote

Answer (score 2):

> Why can't I use `where` on an array?

Because `Array` class does not have instance method called `where`.

Since `feedbacks.class` is `Array`, you get an error.

You have two options:

1. Define `feedbacks` as instance of `ActiveRecord::Relation` and use [`where`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-where)
2. Not using `where` but appropriate methods from  [`Array`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html) class.

Comment: Andrey, thank you. i never heard about make a object a instance of active record. i gonna see this

Comment: Follow-up question: "How to convert an array to an ActiveRecord::Relation?" ;-)

Comment: @Stefan this is everlasting question here on SO :) One should not worry about converting it, instead, he should make sure it is initially properly defined :)

Comment: But to make sure i have to know right? i anyway i'll have to learn how to convert a array to active record

Comment: @nakapaka1 it's relatively easy: You should use proper methods while setting the `feedbacks` variable (meaning, that the collection you are assigning to it is a AR, not Array). So instead of doing something like `feedbacks = Feedback.all.select { |feedback| feedback.name == 'test' }` you should do `feedbacks = Feedback.where(name: 'test')`

Comment: Andrey thank you very much :)

yeah Stefan, i got it. but as i'm learning ruby,  some terms that you guys use   like the where the x code com from i did not get it on in the first time.

Comment: @Stefan I vote for the `Enumerable.convert_to(Class < Enumerable)` method, that converts any enumerable to any other (including `Array`⇒`ActiveRecord::Relation` of course.)

Answer (score 0):

If `Feedback` is your `ActiveRecord` model, you could probably use `Feedback.where('buyer_feedback_date is not null')`.

Comment: I did not downvote, but the question itself is sounding vague, and you have answered it based on Active record, when the op is clearly showing he is using array

Comment: Holger Frohloff i did not  downvoting either! to be honest i even can't vote!
but thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

feedbacks = Feedback.all

Why would you query every entry in this table to get

feedbacks.where('buyer_feedback_date is not null').rated(Feedback::FROM_BUYERS).average(:buyer_rating) || 0

Try this =>

@average_customer_rating =Feedback.where('buyer_feedback_date is not null').rated(Feedback::FROM_BUYERS).average(:buyer_rating) || 0

else

@average_customer_rating = Feedback.where('buyer_feedback_date is not null').rated(Feedback::FROM_BUYERS).average(:buyer_rating) || 0

Should scope it to cust_feedback